# cannot add new tags through jquery.tokeninput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on, jquery-tokeninput

I have watched numerous times both ryan rails-casts, however I'm stuck on this issue couple of days. The main problem is I cannot set new tag records with jquery.tokeninput nor without jquery. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with wrong routes setup... Thank you in advance!

#prepopulating form works fine

_form.html.haml

```
= f.text_field :tag_list, data: {load: @job.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json }
```

job.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#job_tag_list').tokenInput '/jobs/tags.json',
  theme: 'facebook'
  prePopulate: $('#job_tag_list').data('load')
```

job.rb

```
attr_accessible :tag_list


def self.tokens(query)

  tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
  if tags.empty?
    [{id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "Add new skill:  \"#{query}\""}]
  else
    tags
  end
end


def self.tag_list=(arguments)
  return if !arguments.is_a?(Hash)
  list = arguments[:tag_list]
  list.gsub!(/<<<(.+?)>>>/) { ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name: $1).name }
end
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
def tags

  @tags  = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where("tags.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => @tags.tokens(params[:q])}
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
    resources :jobs do
    member do
      post 'reply'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I have no experience of using jquery-tokeninput with ruby, and the set up is somewhat different - but in the native Javascript version, you would need to use the parameter `allowFreeTagging:true` in what is here `job.js.coffee` - maybe try it as a potential quick fix?

Comment: looks like you don't have a route defined for the path "/jobs/tags.json", add "get 'tags', on: :collection" inside the jobs resource route.

Answer (score 1):

the workable integration of act_as_taggable_one and jquery.tokeninput is provided below:

Extract files from here:https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput and put in corresponding folders:

**vendor/assets/javascripts**
**vendor/assets/stylesheets**

gemfile

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
```

application.css

```
 *= require token-input-facebook
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery.tokeninput
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "jquery.tokeninput" %>
```

jobs.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#job_tag_list').tokenInput '/jobs/tags.json',
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#job_tag_list').data('load')
    allowCustomEntry: true
```

_form.html.haml

```
= f.text_field :tag_list, data: {load: @job.tags.map{|t| {id: t.name, name: t.name}}.to_json}
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
def tags
    @tags  = Job.tokens(params[:q])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => @tags}
    end
  end
```

job.rb

```
acts_as_taggable
attr_accessible :tag_list

def self.tokens(query)
    tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where("tags.name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
    if tags.empty?
      [{id: "#{query}", name: "Add new skill:  \"#{query}\""}]
    else
      tags
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :jobs do
    member do
      post 'reply'
    end
      get 'tags', on: :collection
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#skills").tokenInput("/url",{
        theme: "facebook",
        onResult: function (results) {
            if ( results.length == 0 ){
              result = new Object();
              result['id']    = $('#token-input-skills').val();
              result['name']  = $('#token-input-skills').val();
              results.push(result);
            }
            return results;
        }
      });
```

i added a function that populates the array with the user's input text if no results are available